# Finding regions in Choroplet map

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I am trying to prepare Choropleth map for Kosovo. My intention is to map following districts/regions : Ferizaj, Gjakova,Gjilan,Mitrovica,Pecki,Pristina and  Prizren.

I tried to do this with ggplot2 and below you can see my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
mapdata_df <- map_data("world") 

sub_set<-mapdata_df%>%
    dplyr::filter(region %in%  c("Kosovo"))
```

But inside in the ggplot2 although I found Kosovo I can't find names of the regions. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and prepare choropleth map with regions ?

Comment: They don't seem to exist in the world map you've downloaded. `map_data("world")` pulls a world map from the public domain Natural Earth project, which has regions like Kosovo, but won't have detailed district-level data like Pristina or Gjakova. You can use another package like `osmdata` to download these administrative boundaries or you can directly download them from an authoritative and import them into R using the `sf` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate my comment, here's how you can create a map of the different districts in Kosovo using `osmdata` and `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(osmdata)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright

q <- getbb("kosovo") |>
  opq() |>
  add_osm_feature(key = "admin_level", value = "4") |>
  osmdata_sf()

kosovo_districts <- q |>
  purrr::pluck("osm_multipolygons") |>
  dplyr::filter(`is_in:country`=="Republic of Kosovo")

ggplot(data = kosovo_districts) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = `name:en`)) +
  theme_void()
```

Which gives the output:
[image: Map of Kosovo districts]

The [OpenStreetMap wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative#admin_level=*_Country_specific_values) shows which administrative level to request to return districts, and can also be modified to return national borders as well. Since the bounding box for Kosovo also returns a few district-equivalent boundaries from Serbia, I filter those out. Hope this helps you out!

<sup>Created on 2024-03-22 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>